# Joomla component doesn't show Permissions actions

Tags: joomla, permissions, components, joomla2.5, acl

I am creating a new component that has a **Permissions** tab like other components using config.xml and access.xml files.

but i have a weird problem, everything is fine when i install it on localhost but when i install the component on my host on the web it doesn't show the actions for access levels (Configure,  Access Administration Interface, Create, Edit, Edit state, Edit own).

other components work fine and my component works fine on localhost.

i tested it on cPanel and Direct Admin and again the same problem happens.

does anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the code from com_weblinks/config.xml to my component config.xml file and it worked!

```
<fieldset name="permissions"
        description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC"
        label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL">
        <field name="rules" type="rules"
               component="com_component_name"
               filter="rules"
               validate="rules"
               label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL"
               section="component" />
</fieldset>
```

I found I had entered my component name in capital letters `component="COM_COMPONENT_NAME"`, so cPanel and Direct admin both were case sensitive about this, but localhost didn't care!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have "config.xml" abd "access.xml" at "administrator/components/com_component_name" from the root folder of Joomla.

if they are not, you can manually upload then at above mentioned destination by FTP or Cpanel Upload.

let me know if it doesn't works.

Comment: All files are in the right places and i uploaded them via FTP but it didn't work again. I will try to use other component access.xml and config.xml files and check the result.

Comment: @Alir3za ,can you please check if you have below line in config.xml:   
    

<fieldset name="permissions" label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL" description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC" >
<field name="rules" type="rules" label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL" filter="rules" validate="rules" component="com_installer" section="component" />
</fieldset>

Comment: Yes, the problem solved by using lowercase letters for component name! thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

With Joomla I always have problems with file permissions on the server. So if your hosting server is linux, check the file permissions to be sure they can be opened by the Joomla module - files with 644 permissions could be problematic. I am not saying you should change them immediately - this is an ugly hack and its a security issue.

Comment: I changed file permissions but it did not work. also all other files of joomla have the same file permissions.